# GPS service not used if switched on in Activity

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am writing a code in order to be able to use localisation (GPS based if available else Network based). Everything works fine if I enter my activity with GPS turned ON on my mobile.
But if i enter the Activity with GPS turned off and then i enable GPS while in the Activity nothing happens and NETWORK based location is still active instead of switching to GPS based.

Did i miss something ?
Thanks

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    //Used CameraPosition attributes
    private final int MAP_BEARING = 69;
    private final int SETUP_ZOOM = 16;
    private final int AT_POSITION_ZOOM = 19;
    private final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 20000; //Update frequency (ms)
    private final LatLng MAP_CENTER = new LatLng(44.80736, -0.596572);

    private CheckBox mServices, mRestauration, mBuildings;
    private Resources mResources;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private Marker mCurrentLocation;
    private ArrayList<Marker> mServicesMarkers, mRestaurationMarkers, mBuildingsMarkers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mResources = getResources();
        mServices = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.services_check);
        mRestauration = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.restauration_check);
        mBuildings = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.buildings_check); 
        setUpLocationServices();
    }

    public void setUpLocationServices() {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        mCurrentLocation = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(currentPosition)
        .title("Votre position")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.user_location_marker)));   

        if (location != null)
            onLocationChanged(location);
        if (isGpsEnabled())
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        else
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, UPDATE_FREQUENCY, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation.remove();
        LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mCurrentLocation = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(currentPosition)
        .title("Votre position")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.user_location_marker)));      
    }

    public boolean isGpsEnabled() {
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (isGpsEnabled()) 
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,  this);
        else 
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, UPDATE_FREQUENCY, 0, this);               
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (isGpsEnabled())
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        else 
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, UPDATE_FREQUENCY, 0, this);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: No ideas about the problem ? =(

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
  if (isGpsEnabled())
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
  else
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, UPDATE_FREQUENCY, 0, this);
```

You run this code only once, in `onCreate()`.  If you want location updates once the GPS has been enabled, you need to ask for it.  On modern devices, I prefer to use [Google's Play Service Location API](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) with a Fused Location provider.  This is how I implemented in my last commercial application, falling back to GPS only if Google Play wasn't installed.

Another option, if you [look at this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate), at the `isBetterLocation` method, you can compare your current value to the new one, and choose the better of the two.  That way, if you have one and get the other, you can decide whether it's a better location than you had previously.