# longitude and latitude points change for the same place

Tags: java, android

I am Android developer.

I am getting the longitude and latitude point of a place but for the same place these values changes and the third decimal varies.

My main purpose is to detect a place so it works only
when all these values of longitude and latitude matches so they must
be constant.

My questions are:

- What is the reason for this variation?
- Is there any method by which ti make these values remain constant for a specific place?

Answer (score 2):

The phone's GPS isn't very accurate. That is, it is very accurate for navigate in your car, but missing by 20 meters is not unheard of.

To figure out if you're in the same place, you should calculate the distance between your current location and the place's coordinates. If it's lower than a threshold (try to find one that makes sense) - you're there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `GPS` for more accurate data, but know that they will not be the same values everytime, but not very different either

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the accuracy as well.  The [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class has a `getAccuracy()` method -- if your accuracy decreased from the last method, it may be that the person went inside and lost line-of-sight to the sky.

As I [have said before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342726/gps-service-not-used-if-switched-on-in-activity/20573924#20573924) in other posts, I recommend using [Google's Play Location service](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) rather than the pure GPS.  You can also use an `isBetterLocation` method as [documented here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate).

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the GPS inherent accuracy isn't the best.  For an idea of how the decimal places show accuracy levels, see [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees)

In short, the third decimal place results in an accuracy differential of 43-111 meters, depending on your position on the globe.  So I would either look at some other method of refining the data, or implementing some sort of threshold processing.